# instagram api, posting a like

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, instagram

I'm working with the instagram API, and unfortunately I've got kind of stuck.
After setting everything up I have a like/dislike button for each instagram image that calls the method below.

```
vote = function(type, at, mid){
    // type = POST or DELETE
    // at = access_token
    // mid = media_id
    $.ajax({
        type: type,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        crossDomain:true,
        url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/"+mid+"/likes?access_token="+at,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

It returns message(200, OK), suggesting that my like was counted, however neither likes or dislikes  are actually counted. Thoughts on what might cause the hiccup?

Comment: Are you saying that an upvote = a like on Instagram? Then what is a downvote?

Comment: Sorry, yes, upvote = like, downvote = dislike, changed it in the post... I need to get off reddit

Comment: Hello, could you please tell me how do you access to this end point. I need to access relation endpoint and I'm still in develope and they won't give me access and I don't have any idea how to ask them because its an follow and unfollow app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross domain ajax requests can only be type of `OPTIONS`, if remote [HTTP access control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control) is not configured otherwise. And Instagram is not.

So this is will be server-side job. Make that ajax request to your own URL what is going to make request (with CURL probably) to Instagram.

If you don't need response, you can "fake" that request. Make HTML  and submit

Comment: Yeah I ended up doing the php request with CURL, but I really hoped I could have used ajax instead. What I'm making is going on tumblr, and tumblr really doesn't like php all that much, it also took about 5 times as long to make

Comment: @auguest Bjornberg can you show me how you did php request with curl? i am in situation trying to make delete like request from withing ajax.

Comment: Just fyi, you don't have to go through your own URL. You can still fake DELETE through POST by using method=PUT or method=DELETE as a parameter and it will do the job. @Anpher

Comment: use _method=DELETE actually (forgot the underscore) @AugustBjornberg

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code.

```
var access_token = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/"+mid+"/likes?access_token="+at
var url = 
$.post(url, {access_token: access_token},
 function(data) {
   alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
}, "json");
```